# Heroku PostgreSQL - how does an SSL connection occur without certificates?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku

I have a Heroku PostgreSQL database. Using the credentials (host, database, username, password) supplied by Heroku, I can connect from my local machine using the [PSequel](http://www.psequel.com/) client. Since Heroku requires SSL, I have to check off "Use SSL", which causes additional fields to appear (client key, client certificate, server root certificate). However, Heroku does not provide such certificates. I am able to connect to the database by checking off "Use SSL", but without providing those certificates to PSequel.

How does this work? I was under the impression that certificates are needed for an SSL connection. Without certificates, my understanding is that you could do key exchange and have encryption, but you don't know who you are talking to, so you are vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack. According to my understanding, I must not be connecting to my Heroku PostgreSQL database with SSL, or am I wrong?

In the past, I have used Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) and [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/). In that setup, I set my Cloud SQL settings to require SSL, and Google provided me with certificates (client key, client cert, and server CA) that I then supplied to Sequel Pro in order to connect using SSL. If I try to connect without supplying the certs (but checking off "Connect using SSL", and entering the correct host, username, password), I am not able to connect, and instead get "access denied".

Answer (score 1):

You should [ask PSequel](https://github.com/psequel/psequel/issues), as this is not open source, so I cannot look at the code.

Normally, when a PostgreSQL server is set up for SSL connections, the client can force SSL connections by using the connection option `sslmode=require`, and you don't need to have a client certificate for that (SSL is used for encryprion then, not for authentication).